# Find out actual width of text in nested lists

Tags: lists, minipage, width, nesting

I am trying to solve the following problem:

In regular text, I can place two paragraphs of unequal width side by side using minipages, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Some text here ...
\par\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
   Some text here...
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
   Some other text here...
\end{minipage}
Some more text here...
\end{document}
```

In a first level of a list environment, it is little bit more tricky, but it can be done this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\begin{document}
Some text here ...
\begin{itemize}
   \item Some text...\addtolength{\mywidth}{-\leftmargin}
      \setlength{\mywidth}{\textwidth}
      \addtolength{\mywidth}{-\leftmargin}
      \addtolength{\mywidth}{-\rightmargin}
      \par\noindent%
      \begin{minipage}{.6\mywidth}
         Some text here...
      \end{minipage}%
      \begin{minipage}{.4\mywidth}
         Some other text here...
      \end{minipage}
      Some more text here...
   \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

That will not work inside nested list environments, though, unless one manually keeps track of the width for each level.

Is there any way one can figure out the currect text width regardless of the level of list environments?

Comment: You can use `linegoal` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In lists, LaTeX maintains `\linewidth` that's what you're looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{itemize}
   \item \lipsum*[3]
      \par\noindent%
      \begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
      \lipsum[3]
      \end{minipage}%
      \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
      \lipsum[3]
      \end{minipage}

   \lipsum[2]
   \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```